# compare two dataframes row by row to extract a feature from one into the other (efficiency improvement)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1`, `df2`. Both of them have the same columns but `df2` has a so called `id` column which I want to extract and put into `df1['id_frame']` only if the dataframe rows are equal.

```
ind = merged.columns.get_loc('id_frame')
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
for i_row in range(len(df1)):
    for j_row in range(len(df2)):
        if df1[['material', 'type', 'size', 'height', 'size_in', 'size_cm', 'weight', 'dims']].iloc[i_row]\
                   .equals(df2[['material', 'type', 'size', 'height', 'size_in', 'size_cm', 'weight', 'dims']].iloc[j_row]):
            df2.iloc[j_row, ind] = df1['id'].iloc[i_row]
    tmp = pd.concat([tmp, df2[df2['id'].notna()]])
    df2 = df2[df2['id'].isna()]
df2= tmp
```

The code above works fine but its not efficient at all. How would you improve it?

`df2` has a lot of duplicates removing which would do the trick but I need to keep the indices to make the assignment to the specific object hence I'm not sure how to do it with this approach.

Comment: try `pd.merge` and use all `['material', 'type', 'size', 'height', 'size_in', 'size_cm', 'weight', 'dims']` as the merging keys? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Brilliant! How didn't I think of that. Write it as an answer and I will close the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For those wondering to keep the index, since merging resets the indices, I save them in a column using ```reset_index()``` function and then ```set_index("index")``` after the merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pd.merge` and use all of `['material', 'type', 'size', 'height', 'size_in', 'size_cm', 'weight', 'dims']` as the merging keys.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html